# Does this program have a limit?

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with this code. Although it should say that this number is not prime, as i put a ridiculously large number that i know to be nonprime (252345435465, or even 1000000000000 as an example), it states that the number is prime.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int n;
int i;
int prime = true;

cout << "Type in a number and press ENTER: ";
cin >> n;

i = 2;
while (i <= sqrt(n)) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}

if (prime)
    cout << "The number is prime" << endl;
else
    cout << "The number is NOT prime" << endl;

system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ever consider that the values in your example are bigger than the maximum int value?

Answer (score 2):

The values you are putting in are too big for an `int` to hold.  They are overflowing the 32 bit limit of a signed int (-2147483648 through 2147483647).

Comment: Note that the limits shown above are for a particular C++ implementation. Windows C++ compilers, even 64-bit, will have these limits. Other compilers may have larger or smaller limits (the *minimum* limits for `int` are -32.767 to +32.767, inclusive, IIRC, for 16-bit sign-and-magnitude representation).

Answer (score 2):

First, to avoid including the non-standard header `<stdafx.h>`, just turn off **precompiled headers** in your Visual C++ project (right click the project, then properties).

The main problem is that you're inputting values too large for the `int` type.

To detect that, simply check the state of the stream after the input operation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>  // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int n;
int i;
int prime = true;

cout << "Type in a number and press ENTER: ";
cin >> n;
if( cin.fail() )
{
    cout << "Sorry, that's not a valid `int` number." << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

i = 2;
while (i <= sqrt(n)) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}

if (prime)
    cout << "The number is prime" << endl;
else
    cout << "The number is NOT prime" << endl;

system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's actually nothing non-standard about `stdafx.h`. It's just another header, as far as standard C++ is concerned. Of course, using any header violates the idea of a self-contained example.

Comment: @MSalters: There are two non-standard issues. First, the most obvious, it's not a header defined by the C++ standard. This is what's usually meant by **non-standard header**, and is the sense in which I used that term. Secoondly, its purpose is to support Microsoft precompiled headers (it is "the" precompiled header in a typical Visual Studio project), which defines a language subtly different from standard C++, so that some valid C++ standard code does not compile (novices are often baffled by this), and so that some invalid C++ code does compile.

Answer (score 1):

A 32-bit `signed int` can take a range of values between –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Your number is too large for that range.

Either use a more suitable variable type, or only input numbers which are within range for the variable you are using.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/1227469) for more information on C++ data types and their ranges.